# If my question was closed, how come I've had downvotes since closing

Tags: support, down-votes, closed-questions

Okay, I'm not disputing the closing question because that was fair enough. I'm concerned that my question was downvoted **after** my question was closed and this doesn't seem fair.

I've asked a question that doesn't belong on the website, and as a result it was closed. It appears I can get repeatedly 'punished' even after my question was closed. Is this really the case? Can you downvote after a question has been closed? If so, what's the logic behind this?

Now, I may be jumping the gun and in-fact the votes occurred before it was closed, and this is still fine obviously. I'm just worried that some closed questions of mine may still come back to haunt me.

Question was - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364005/drupal-how-to-hide-a-block-entirely-if-its-empty#comment11827769_9364005

Comment: Problem solved - it's now deleted. No more votes. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any point to downvoting already closed questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113955/any-point-to-downvoting-already-closed-questions)

Answer (score 10):

Closed is not the same as locked. If the post was locked then no voting would be allowed.

Closed is also meant to be a temporary state. A closed question can go one of two ways:

1. It's edited to fix the issues that caused it to be closed in the first place and reopened.
2. It's deleted as it's unsalvageable.

Voting is left enabled so that that people can see at a glance which category it lies in.

If the question really doesn't belong on the site then delete it. If you can't delete it yourself (if it has answers or is too new) then flag it for moderator attention. However, once a question gets a negative score it can become eligible for automatic deletion, [the rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) are quite complicated, but basically if there are no answers scoring > 0 then it will get deleted.

On a personal note: I don't down-vote an already closed, down-voted question. There's no benefit to me (I can already cast a delete vote if I want) and there's no benefit to you (you already know the question is off topic).

Comment: One case for adding a downvote to a particularly terrible closed question would be to aid the automatic question-asking ban for users who repeatedly ask bad questions.